# Копирование класса с его данными полей

Tags: java

У меня есть класс POJO, соответственно в нем присутствуют поля с геттерами. Мне необходимо создать дубликат класса, но не экземпляр, через ключевое слово `new`, а именно копию, что бы все данные из переменных и коллекций остались при себе. Подтолкните пожалуйста на реализацию.

Comment: нужно создавать кастомный clon method  в pojo классе.

Comment: @Санаев а можно хоть немного подробнее?

Comment: в ответе напишу как я бы сделал

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала имплементируем Cloneable интерфейс. Далее переопределяем метод `clone()`

```
class PojoClassOne implements Cloneable{
    private String field;

    public PojoClassOne(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}

class PojoClassTwo implements Cloneable {
    private PojoClassOne pojoClassOne;
    private List<PojoClassOne> listFields;

    public List<PojoClassOne> getListFields() {
        return listFields;
    }

    public void setListFields(List<PojoClassOne> listFields) {
        this.listFields = listFields;
    }



  @Override
  protected PojoClassTwo clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    PojoClassTwo pojoClassTwo =  (PojoClassTwo) super.clone();
    List<PojoClassOne> pojoClassOnes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (PojoClassOne field : listFields){
        pojoClassOnes.add((PojoClassOne) field.clone());
    }
    pojoClassTwo.setListFields(pojoClassOnes);
    pojoClassTwo.setPojoClassOne((PojoClassOne) 
    this.getPojoClassOne().clone());
    return pojoClassTwo;
}

    public PojoClassOne getPojoClassOne() {
        return pojoClassOne;
    }

    public void setPojoClassOne(PojoClassOne pojoClassOne) {
        this.pojoClassOne = pojoClassOne;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        PojoClassTwo pojoClass = new PojoClassTwo();
        pojoClass.setPojoClassOne(new PojoClassOne("field"));
        List<PojoClassOne> fields = Arrays.asList(new PojoClassOne("field1"), new PojoClassOne("field2"), new PojoClassOne("field3"));
        pojoClass.setListFields(fields);
        PojoClassTwo pojoClassClon = (PojoClassTwo) pojoClass.clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: сейчас обновлю ответ. правильнее это сделать через Cloneable

Comment: Выглядит именно так, как мне надо. Я правильно понимаю, что данный метод сработает и для коллекций?

Comment: @ВладиславЖерихов смотря какая коллекция. Если коллекция с кастомным объектом, то в нем нужно также имплементировать cloneable

Comment: значит мне придется проделать это со всеми коллекциями) хорошо, спасибо

Comment: @ВладиславЖерихов нечайно удалил лишнее. обновил ответ